# angular *ngIf- check if array in specific index null

Tags: html, angular, angular-ng-if

I want to check if array in specific index is not null
this is my code:

```
    *ngIf="routeService?.selectedPlaces?[index]!=null"
```

'routeService' is service that the component gets in its constractor and 'selectedPlaces' is array in the service.
'index' is property in the component.

I got this error:

```
    main.ts:13 Error: Template parse errors:
    Parser Error: Conditional expression routeService?.selectedPlaces?[index]!=null requires all 3 
    expressions at the end of the expression [routeService?.selectedPlaces?[index]!=null] in 
    ng:///PlaceAutocompleteFromDBComponent/template.html@5:29 ("-field class="example-full-width">
```

How can I check it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Typescript the `elvis operator` syntax is `?.`
In the second case, you have used only `?`, which is not valid.
You need to to use

```
*ngIf="routeService?.selectedPlaces && routeService.selectedPlaces[index]"
```

Comment: The safe navigation operator `?.` is defined in Angular templates, not in Typescript.

Comment: @ConnorsFan Check newer version of typescript - https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#optional-chaining

Comment: Thanks for the info. I wasn't aware of that.